# Use an extension method in a DynamicLinq-query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, telerik

I want to extend the filter behavior of a Telerik RadGrid.
If the user for instance filters the grid with the following word "michele" it should also return the rows which include "michèle". This isn't supported out-of-the-box in the Telerik RadGrid.
Therefore I wrote a extension method for the type String: `public static bool IsSqlLikeMatch( this string input, string pattern ) { [...] }`

As a second step I replaced the FilterExpression of the RadGrid like this:

```
this.MasterTableView.FilterExpression.Replace( "Contains", "IsSqlLikeMatch" );
```

But unfortunately I get the following error message:

> No applicable method 'IsSqlLikeMatch' exists in type 'String'

The Telerik RadGrid uses DynamicLinq. So therefore my question: "Can I use extension methods in DynamicLinq"? And how do I accomplish this?

**Edit 09/09/2011:**
I've contacted the Telerik support and this was their answer:

> Unfortunately you could not extend the dynamic linq functions included into Telerik.Web.UI.dll. So your changes to the DynamicLinq class will not effected the ExpressionParser used internally into the RadControls. However you could try changing the Dynamic Linq library and perform custom filtering by getting the filter expression from the RadGrid parse and pass them to the changed Dynamic Linq class' method and bind the RadGrid to the returned data. I have attached a small sample which demonstrates how to use RadGrid's filter/sort expressions to filter, sort and page through ObjectDataSource.

Comment: What namespace is the method `IsSqlLikeMatch` in?

Comment: It wrote a class which holds all my extension methods but I didn't specify a namespace for this class.

Comment: You might want to try putting it in the `System.Linq` namespace - I'm not sure that I advise this as a long-term solution, however it would be interesting to see if the method is then found.

Comment: @Kragen Good thinking! But unfortunately it doesn't work...

Comment: I've found this article (http://blog.walteralmeida.com/2010/05/advanced-linq-dynamic-linq-library-add-support-for-contains-extension-.html)... maybe this is the way to go. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use an extension method, you must have a `using` directive for the namespace of the class in which you defined the extension method.

So try putting your class in a namespace, and add `using` for it.

Also, be sure that this class is defined as public static.

Comment: I've added my static class in the namespace System.Linq.Dynamic but it doesn't get recognized.

Comment: If you still haven't solved the problem, you can post the code that doesn't work, so someone may see what's wrong.

Comment: I've added the answer from the Telerik support in my question. Not really an ideal solution...